# What does this expression mean? "¡Ni qué buenas ni qué nada!"

Tags: modismos, significado

Can someone explain to me this expression I heard from a friend?

> ¡Ni qué buenas ni qué nada!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It may be that the person is mad or joking, but it depends on the context. Please add further info on this.

Comment: Without context, it sounds as an angry person's answer to a greeting such as "buenas tardes".

Comment: It seems that is disagree with your affirmation. "buenas"

Answer (score 6):

In Spanish there are some expressions to show disagreement with something previously expressed. In [this link](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BTctS7T) you can search for the expression *ni qué ocho cuartos*, used in a very similar way to what you heard:

> ¡Qué buenas ni qué ocho cuartos!

Another similar expression is *[ni qué niño muerto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QW5mMvv)*:

> ¡Qué buenas ni qué niño muerto!

Probably, the day you said "¡buenas!" (or maybe "¡buenas tardes!") to that person, there was a bad weather, or maybe that person was not having a good day at all, so he/she just showed disagreement (maybe in an angry way). The expression *ni qué nada* is similar to those mentioned, just shorter.

Comment: _¿Niño muerto!!!_ Son bastante bestias ustedes los españoles...

Comment: @Rodrigo pues sí, es verdad, la fama de malhablados que tenemos en Hispanoamérica la tenemos ganada a pulso...